# How can I compress and create mp4 video file from batch of images on hard disk using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

In my directory I copied ffmpeg.exe to the same directory where all the images are.
All images are bitmaps.

Then in the command prompt windows I typed:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r  out.mp4
```

But I get error that there is no a directory name:

> \.\pipe\mytestpipe

So I removed it and typed the same line without the pipe part.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i -map 0 -c:v mpeg4 -r  out.mp4
```

Now there is no a directory name -map

So I moved the `-map 0`

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1920x1080 -i -c:v mpeg4 -r  out.mp4
```

Now I'm getting error:

> -c:v: Protocol not found

I used this line with the pipe in my c# program as arguments to ffmpeg using `ProcessStartInfo` but now I don't want to use pipes only in the command prompt to type it and compress and create mp4 video file.

Edit I tried this now:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

And what I get is some errors:

```
E:\screenshots>ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30 -p
ix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-73165-gf1e1730 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 45.100 / 56. 45.100
  libavformat    56. 38.102 / 56. 38.102
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 18.100 /  5. 18.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[bmp @ 0000000002eb7f80] bad magic number
    Last message repeated 2 times
[image2 @ 0000000002eb64e0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 0000000002eb64e0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video:
 bmp, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
screenshot%06d.bmp: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, image2, from 'screenshot%06d.bmp':
  Duration: 00:07:35.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, none, 0.20 fps, 0.20 tbr, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

For those who can see. When i'm doing it on a single file for example: `ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot000002.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out1.mp4` or `screenshot000003.bmp` or `screenshot000122.bmp` it will work fine and create the video file. But when i'm doing this for all images i'm getting all the errors: `ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4` [here](http://pastebin.com/HCjHYE25) is the results when i did on `screenshot000002.bmp` and it worked fine.

When i'm doing it on a single image file it's working fine like `screenshot000002.bmp` but when doing it on all the images `screenshot%06d.bmp` it's giving me all the errors i mentioned above.

Comment: I found the problem. ffmpeg dosen't work with Bitmaps. Once i changed the images on my hard disk saved them as jpeg(jpg) and then doing the line ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -p
ix_fmt yuv420p out2.mp4 and it's working perfect.

Comment: `ffmpeg` should have no issue with BMP inputs. Please provide a sample image.

Comment: LordNeckbeard dunno now it's working with bitmaps. Maybe since i saved the bitmaps using also System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp when saving the images and not only ".bmp" but it seems to be working now. I tried with 10 files. I will try now with mroe files and see if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fundamental issue. You need to read the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) first. `-i` is for input. So you need to specify the input images here. You can find many resources for creating a video out of a given images. Better look [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images).

To clarify further `-map 0` is for mapping first input to the output. And `-c:v` is for specifying the video codec for encoding.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Edited my question with the errors i get.  When i used the arguments with ProcessStartInfo i didn't get any errors like bad magic number or Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 .

Comment: @BrubakerHaim Add the full uncut console output (pastebin)

Comment: Also when i type ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30 -p
ix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 i get the errors but i also i see the file created on the hard disk and it look like a music file. Not video file.

Comment: I tried for test now to make instead out.mp4 but out.mpeg4 and instead screenshot%06d.bmp only one file: screenshot000001.bmp and i get this error: http://pastebin.com/6VsERgRB

Comment: @BrubakerHaim the command you are giving has a wrong option. there is nothing like `-p ix_fmt`. it have to be `-pix_fmt`. With that, your command works fine for me. `ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Comment: @BrubakerHaim I tried you command with several `bmp` images and it works properly. What I'm guessing is there can be some issues with your images. Try with some different.

Comment: Chamath i tried this now only one file: ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot000001.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30
-pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 and it was working fine. But when i'm trying to do it all over the files like this: ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i screenshot%06d.bmp -c:v libx264 -r 30
-pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 then i get this errors.

Comment: Chamath you right something wrong with the bmp files. Maybe since they are not all in same size ? Some 1.21mb some 1.30mb

Comment: @BrubakerHaim size of the file doesn't matter like that variation. You better include some of your image file information with `ffmpeg -i screenshot000002.bmp`. Then it will help someone else to figure out the issue.